# How to update initial data in android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app have predefined categories and store in xml. When app install first time, load the xml and insert into to sqlite db and I use SharedPreferences varialbe called "isDataLoad=false" to prevent to insert again when app load again.

But now I want to add more categories and release with new version. After user update the app, how to insert again because my SharedPreferences varialbel is "isDataLoad=true".

What is the best way to only update the preferences data when new release?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You should change the version of your database and handle that situation in the onUpgrade method in your SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  switch(oldVersion) {
    case PREVIOUS_VERSION:
    //Perform the change to your database
    break;
  }
}
```